# CAST and CASE in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I'm trying to return a string when certain conditions are true, but the I'm running into a data type issue... LI.num_seats_pur and LI.num_seats_ret are both smallint data types...

Here's where I'm stuck:

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN (LI.num_seats_ret = LI.num_seats_pur)
    THEN 'RET'
  ELSE (LI.num_seats_pur - LI.num_seats_ret)
END as 'Seats'

FROM T_LINEITEM LI;
```

I understand that 'RET' is obviously not a smallint, but every combination of CAST I use here is still causing an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a `CASE` expression, if the return values have different data types, they will be converted to the one with the higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). And since `SMALLINT` has a higher precedence than `VARCHAR`, the return value of the `ELSE` part, `'RET'` gets converted to `SMALLINT`. This will then proceed to a conversion error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'RET' to data type smallint.

In order to achieve the desired result, you need to `CAST` the `ELSE` part to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (LI.num_seats_ret = LI.num_seats_pur)
            THEN 'RET'
        ELSE 
            CAST((LI.num_seats_pur - LI.num_seats_ret) AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS 'Seats'
FROM T_LINEITEM LI;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the precedence clarification... That's what hung me up... This did the trick!